# Creating Images from SQL Server BLOBs is painfully slow

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Has anyone had any issues when converting a BLOB (jpg) from SQL Server 2008 to a file on your file system?  It's taking upward of 5-8 seconds for the blob to be retrieved then file created

ultimately I'm gonna store the filepaths and do quick lookups like that but for the initial hit per jpeg, it takes a long time to create the file and I have to assume there's a way to make it faster or I'm just doing it wrong or in an inefficient way in C#.

Here's how I'm getting it from the DB:

```
memberPhoto.PhotoBinary = (byte[])reader.GetValue(ordinals[(int)Enums.MemberPhotoColumn.PhotoBinary])
```

Here's how I'm creating the file off that:

```
        using (FileStream file = File.Create(photoPhysicalFilepath))
        {
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(file);
            writer.Write(photoBinary);
            writer.Flush();
        }

        return relativePhotoFilePath;
```

photoBinary is the byte[] value I got from the datareader.

Not sure if this is efficient.  I've seen people go this route but don't understand if this is an old way to do it and I've found a more syntactically elegant way of doing it or if my way is just a more elegant way I've found:

```
                 fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Create);

                    fs.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
                    fs.Close();

                    MimeType = image.MIMEType;

where imageData is again a byte[]
```

So I'm wondering if anyone has done it my way or do you typically go with the second syntax...has there been any performance gains from the second vs. first on a large scaled website that anyone has encountered?

ultimately just trying to figure out why it's taking so long for the blob to file creation.

Comment: While you will pay a price for using SQL BLOBS, it shouldn't be *that* big. However, since you have posted no sources, it could be anything.

Comment: I'll post source in a few...